# replace linebreaks to get them working with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, line-breaks

I have following small script to preview some text before submitting it to store in a database:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var input = $('#contents'),
    preview = $('#previewaccordion div.viewcontents');

    input.keyup(function(e) {
        preview.html(input.val());
    });
});
```

but if I type text with line-breaks it ignores them and writes all of them in one line. How could I replace the line-breaks so that they show correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that you are using a textarea for the input. There are \n used as linebreaks, which have no influence in HTML. So you have to replace them with br-tags:

```
input.val().replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
```

Comment: This will replace the first occurrence of line break only, to replace all occurrences you should use /\n/g

Answer (score 5):

It's nothing to do with jQuery: Linebreaks in HTML are not significant, they're just whitespace (like spaces and tabs).

To force a linebreak in HTML, you use a `<br>` tag. So you could change

```
preview.html(input.val());
```

to

```
preview.html(input.val().replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br>'));
```

Note that you're also not escaping HTML special characters (like `<` or `&`), and so if you type them, your output may not be correct. So you might go with:

```
preview.html(input.val().replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br>'));
```

And finally, I'd hook `keypress` as well as `keyup`, so you see characters created via key repeat (which fires `keypress`, but not `keyup`).

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/apiles) | [source](http://jsbin.com/apiles/edit)

Answer (score 3):

Hiya **demo here:** http://jsfiddle.net/STnhV/1/

hope this helps! cheers!

**Jquery Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#inputfoo').keyup(function() {
       $('#outputbar').html($(this).val().replace(/\n/g,'<br/>')); 
    });
});

​
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the linebreaks to html break tags when you render the output from the database.