# How to pre-fill a textarea based on user input and display preview?

Tags: jquery, textarea

I have a bunch of input forms like email, name, message, etc.. I have made all the fields mandatory. Is it possible with jquery to prefill the message textarea with inputs from other forms but the user can still be able to edit *some* text? My goal is to provide a sort of div preview based on the user's input + other bunch of information. The preview's goal is to show to the user what his/her message would look like in an email message when submitted.
Example below of fields

```
 Name: John Doe
 email: johndoe@example.com
 Institution: Institute of Aquaculture
```

I would like to prefill the message textarea with:

```
To Whom It May Concern:    

Please supply document: {Item requested}. Retrieved from 
{Referring Page}.

I will use the requested material only for private study, scholarship or
research.

Regards,
John Doe<johndoe@example.com>
```

The user can edit the content of the textarea if he/she is not satisfied with the content and would like to add other information.

I want the div preview to display:

```
**This is the text to be sent to the responsible person.**

To Whom It May Concern:    

Please supply document: {Item requested}. Retrieved from 
{Referring Page}

I will use the requested material only for private study, scholarship or
research.

Regards,
John Doe<johndoe@example.com>

Name: {From input form}
Institution: {From input form}
Item requested: {Generated automatically}
Logged In As: {from input form}
Referring Page: {Generated automatically}
```

Please note that **Item requested** and **Referring Page** were generated automatically. I searched in stackoverflow on [how to pre-fill/populate a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545573/jquery-to-populate-input-or-textarea) and [how to generate a preview based on input forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963158/replace-linebreaks-to-get-them-working-with-jquery), but somehow I don't know how to combine these two. Any suggestions on how to achieve this or is this at all possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/qcxmb75z/

Comment: @rogelio, yes, could you please post your answer so that I can accept it? I just figured it myself a while ago but your code is more cleaner. Can you also edit your code so that it will generate the div preview? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, for prefill the textarea, make a string and then replace the values from the input. In this example I enclosed between 2 colons the word for replace later:

```
var text = "Some text here, this is the :name: from input";

text = text.replace(':name:', $('#name').val());
```

See the full example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qcxmb75z/1/)

Comment: Just to complete my answer. with `text.replace(/:name:/g, "the_text")` you can replace all occurrences of :name:`